# Running multiple lines of code parallel in different terminals using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am new to programming. I am writing a bash script which runs 2 different programs.
This is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
./ngrok http 3005
node index2.js
```

The first command starts ngrok and the second one starts my local server. I noticed that they are executing one after the other. I want them to run parallel in 2 different terminal in linux. How do I do this?

Comment: I tried this 
#!/bin/bash
node index2.js & ./ngrok http 3005 && fg 
 but got this error --->   ./start.sh: line 3: fg: no job control

Comment: Sounds like you either run the script with `sh scriptname` where `sh` is a shell without job control, or you have a Bash without job control. You can check that with `echo $-`; if the string contains `m`, you do have job control enabled.

Comment: There is no need for a well-behaving sserver to run in the foreground, and indeed it probably doesn't do that particularly well if it's designed to be a server. But if you want to run multiple terminals during developent, I added a duplicate which shows how to do that on X11. Similar arrangements (but probably with different command names) should work on other platforms, or with a different terminal in place of the traditional `xterm`.